# Modo correto de dar valor a uma variável PHP

Tags: php

Peguei um sistema para fazer uma manutenção, porém deparei-me com o seguinte trecho:

```
$nomeUsuario = $_SESSION["NomeUsuario"] = $idUsuario;
```

Ele funciona, porém confesso que costumo usar da forma tradicional:

```
$nomeUsuario = $_SESSION["NomeUsuario"];
$idUsuario = $nomeUsuario;
```

O primeiro modo, apesar de funcionar, pode ser usado?

Comment: Se você acha legível, pode.

Comment: É bem pessoal isso, como usar `if` ou ternário por exemplo, mas pode ser usado sim

Comment: Assim como o @RicardoPontual disse é bem pessoal, eu costumo usar $a=$b=$c, mas em ambas o funcionamento é o mesmo e podem ser usadas.

Answer (score 4):

[Operadores de Atribuição](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.assignment.php)

> O operando da esquerda recebe o valor da expressão da direita

Ou seja, você pode encadear várias variáveis recebendo o mesmo valor, porque a variável da esquerda irá receber o valor da variável da direita.

Exemplo:

**Em formato de múltiplas linhas**

```
$var_a = 'A';
$var_b = 'A';
$var_c = 'A';
$var_d = 'A';
$var_e = 'A';
```

**Atribuição em única linha**

```
$var_a = $var_b = $var_c = $var_d = $var_e = 'A';
```

---

Dado seu exemplo:

```
$nomeUsuario = $_SESSION["NomeUsuario"];
$idUsuario = $nomeUsuario;
```

Verificado com base no seu primeiro exemplo, esse segundo exemplo não é compatível. Pois `$nomeUsuario`e `$_SESSION["NomeUsuario"]` terão o valor de `$idUsuario`.

Portanto essa atribuição `$idUsuario = $nomeUsuario;` não é verdade;

[Exemplo Funcional](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f77e268403edbc0bf932681ae1b1b8573795ce5a)

**Conclusão:**

O formato de atribuição vai depender do que você realmente precisa, a atribuição em uma única linha é útil para atribuição do mesmo valor para várias variáveis. Assim reduz a quantidade de atribuição manual que você precisa realizar.

Esse outro exemplo também é funcional, uma atribuição em uma soma.

```
$a = ($b = 4) + 5; // $a é igual a 9 agora e $b foi definido como 4.
```